# Startup Script with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk (through Visual Studio) to deploy a .NET environment to EC2.  Is there any way to have the equivalent of Azure's startup cmd scripts or powershell scripts?  I know that you can pass scripts through User Data when creating EC2 instances, but is that possible in Elastic Beanstalk?  If not, how can I create a script that executes one time on instance creation?  The main purpose of the script is to download certain resources and to install dependencies before the application starts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes what you want to do is possible. You will need to utilize the .ebextensions mechanism. The AWS Elastic Beanstalk documentation talks about this in detail [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html). For example, to install an MSI on startup you would use this command in a configuration file:

```
packages:
  msi:
    mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Net/mysql-connector-net-6.6.5.msi/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/
```